# How to use Date time picker in mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, datetimepicker

I am new to the MVC and Jquery. I need to choose date time, i have opted below way, but it enable to pick date only i need to pick the time as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#date").datepicker(
    { 
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    showAnim: 'slideDown'
     });
 });
 </script>

 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartTime, new {id = "date"})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have both date and time picker you can use this add-on

[Jquery UI timepicker add-on](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js)

It works with existing jquery datepicker.

You should refer Script files in the following order

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
```

Now simply calls the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#date").datetimepicker({
         dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss' 
    });
 });
 </script>

 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartTime, new {id = "date"})
```

Check this for more [reference](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

Comment: I have used the same way but popup it not appearing to choose date time.

Comment: Initially i had download the Jquery at local and included in the solution, latter i pointed to web by then it worked. Dont know why? Thanks  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>